# Animating UL elements from display: inline block to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of li items in an ul that looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gCtq9/). When the browser is >1440px I want the list to be displayed as `display: inline-block`. When it's <1440px I want it to be the default (I'm not really sure what it's called, but stacking vertically).

Is there a method, either CSS or Javascript, that will allow the li elements to smoothly move from one the horizontal position to the vertical position rather than teleporting?

Comment: Take a look at [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: @PatsyIssa Will it work with list elements?